# How can I do SELECT UNIQUE with LINQ?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, linq, select, unique

I have a list like this:

```
Red
Red
Brown
Yellow
Green
Green
Brown
Red
Orange
```

I am trying to do a SELECT UNIQUE with LINQ, i.e. I want

```
Red
Brown
Yellow
Green
Orange

var uniqueColors = from dbo in database.MainTable
                   where dbo.Property == true
                   select dbo.Color.Name;
```

I then changed this to

```
var uniqueColors = from dbo in database.MainTable
                   where dbo.Property == true
                   select dbo.Color.Name.Distinct();
```

with no success. The first `select` gets ALL the colors, so how do I modify it to only get the unique values?

If there is a better way of structuring this query, more than happy to go that route.

How do I go about editing it so I can have `.OrderBy( "column name" )` i.e. alphabetically by color name, so name property?

I keep getting a message:

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1) is going to mess up the ordering, so you'll have to the sorting after that.

```
var uniqueColors = 
               (from dbo in database.MainTable 
                 where dbo.Property == true 
                 select dbo.Color.Name).Distinct().OrderBy(name=>name);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. Can someone please explain what goes in the .OrderBy() parameters. You have name=>name. Is that name coming from the column name in the DB? Because we have `dbo.Color.Name` then just `name=>name` which hints to me it is not the column name ? Bizarre it also sorts properly if I just change that to `.OrderBy(a=>a)`

Comment: The name of the variable is irrelevant.  It's just {object passed into function} => {object used to sort}.   Since we have already done the Select, the only thing in the collection being sorted is the names.

Comment: Seems like it would be nice if there was an OrderedBy() for ordering by the entire object/record. An extension method would still be calling a delegate for no reason.

Comment: @NetMage - clarify what you mean be "the entire object/record".  Every field?  In what order?  Including the primary key?

Answer (score 21):

```
var uniqueColors = (from dbo in database.MainTable 
                    where dbo.Property == true
                    select dbo.Color.Name).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 10):

Using query comprehension syntax you could achieve the orderby as follows:

```
var uniqueColors = (from dbo in database.MainTable
                    where dbo.Property
                    orderby dbo.Color.Name ascending
                    select dbo.Color.Name).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hmm... that didn't achieve an alphabetic sort - for some reason... I switched ascending and descending and got the same result. Is the distinct statement affecting it? maybe it needs to be orderedby after that ?

Comment: Could try

var uniqueColors = from result in (from dbo in database.MainTable
                                   where dbo.Property
                                   select dbo.Color.Name).Distinct()
                   orderby result ascending;