# Select unique items with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

When I use the following code I get the same items multiple times.

```
XElement neededFiles = new XElement("needed",
    from o in _9nFiles.Elements()
    join t in addedToSitePull.Elements()
         on o.Value equals
         t.Value
    where o.Value == t.Value
    select new XElement("pic", o.Value));
```

I'd like to get only unique items. I saw a Stack Overflow post, *[How can I do SELECT UNIQUE with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519165)*, that used it, and I tried to implement it, but the change had no affect.

The code:

```
XElement neededFiles = new XElement("needed",
(from o in _9nFiles.Elements()
join t in addedToSitePull.Elements()
on o.Value equals
 t.Value
 where o.Value == t.Value
select new XElement("pic", o.Value)).Distinct() );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine the reason this doesn't work is because `XElement.Equals` uses a simple reference equality check rather than comparing the `Value` properties of the two items. If you want to compare the values, you could change it to:

```
_9nfiles.Elements()
    .Join(addedToSitePull, o => o.Value, t => t.Value, (o, t) => o.Value)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(val => new XElement("pic", val));
```

You could also create your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` for comparing two `XElement`s by their values. Note this assumes all values are non-null:

```
public class XElementValueEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
    {
        return x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement x)
    {
        return x.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you could replace the existing call to `Distinct` with `Distinct(new XElementValueEqualityComparer())`.

Comment: +1 despite the fact that I had to implement a bad solution due to time issues ,I'm looking forward to test and learn your solution - thanks Asaf

Answer (score 4):

Distinct doesn't work because XElements are compared by reference, not by value.
The solution is to use another overload of Distinct - Distinct(IEqualityComparer);

You need to implement IEqualityComparer for example as follows:

```
class XElementEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
    {
        #region IEqualityComparer<XElement> Members

        public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
        {
            if (x == null ^ y == null)
                return false;

            if (x == null && y == null)
                return true;

            return x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(XElement obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;

            return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Lee's answer is better because it's more compact. I leave mine simply for example

Comment: +1 thanks for the unswer + the rare advice to use someone else solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution - but really easy.

```
foreach (XElement  pic in neededFiles.Elements())
{
    unSyncedPictures.Add(pic.Value);
}
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
temp.AddRange(unSyncedPictures.Distinct());
```