# Linq Efficiently find if collection contains duplicates using IQueryable.GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

The keyword in this is `Queryable.GroupBy` instead of `Enumerable.GroupBy`

I use EntityFramework and I want to check if there are no duplicate values. Several answers on StackOverflow [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197290/checking-for-duplicates-in-a-list-of-objects-c-sharp) suggest using `GroupBy`

```
IQueryable<MyType> myItems = ...
IQueryable<IGrouping<string, MyType> groupsWithSameName = myItems
.GroupBy(myItem => myItem.Name);
// note: IQueryable!

bool containsDuplicates = groupsWithSameName.Any(group => group.Skip(1).Any());
```

Although this is allowed on IEnumerables, Skip is not supported on an unordered sequence. The *NotSupportedException* suggests using `OrberBy` before using the Skip.

As an alternative I could check if there are groups with more than one element using Count

```
bool containsDuplicates = groupsWithSameName.Any(group => group.Count() > 1);
```

Both methods require to scan all elements in the collection. This is for the 2nd time because they were also scanned to group them.

Is there a method to check for duplicates on an IQueryable more efficiently?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look on [What is the difference between IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet).  And as all of these is deferred execution, I believe it will transform to SQL and execute in SQL and run once only.  Maybe other people can help to explain this in more detail

Comment: @Alex, up till EF 7, GroupBy is always in memory operation, EF does not translate GroupBy to SQL Group By.

Comment: @AkashKava, thanks for your information, learn a lot here

Comment: @AkashKava Why do you think so? I'm using EF6.1.3 and it does `GROUP BY` SQLs.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, I think I misread EF, seems only EF 7 does not translate Group by correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that scanning of all the elements will not be avoided. In any case, the process of finding a duplicate with SQL will look like this:

```
    SELECT
       name, COUNT(*)
    FROM
       MyType
    GROUP BY
       name
    HAVING 
       COUNT(*) > 1
```

It may be worth trying to seek a solution in such a way?:
[Linq with group by having count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078736/linq-with-group-by-having-count)