# SQL Add total sum row for each property

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to create a new total sum row for every state.

Sample table:

```
| State | Item | Amount
    A      X      100
    B      Y      200
    A      Z      100
    B      X      150
```

Result:

```
| State | Item | Amount
    A      X      100
    A      Z      100
 Total A          200
    B      Y      200
    B      X      150
 Total B          350
```

Is there SQL query that I can use to execute that table

Comment: Do you _specifically_ want to do it in SQL? Could you do it in your C# code instead (for example by `ORDER BY State` in SQL and the processing it in order in C#)?

Comment: What is your DBMS version? Some support a `WITH ROLLUP` clause on `GROUP BY` which could do what you want

Comment: @mjwills Yes I can do it in C# code and right now I only loop the table just like in table 1. I've looked into this post too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813580/add-a-new-row-to-datatable-for-sub-total) but I I dont know how to get the parameters from my SQL

Comment: @Nick Version 12, 2014

Comment: @Nick SQL Server sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `ROLLUP` on a `GROUP BY` clause to get intermediate and overall sums over the grouped by fields. In your case you would group by both state and item to get all rows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN State IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total'
            WHEN Item IS NULL THEN CONCAT('Total ', State)
            ELSE State
       END AS State,
       Item, 
       SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM data
GROUP BY ROLLUP(State, Item)
```

Output:

```
State           Item    Amount
A               X       100
A               Z       100
Total A         (null)  200
B               X       150
B               Y       200
Total B         (null)  350
Grand Total     (null)  550
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ac7dd/3)

Comment: Does `ROLLUP` guarantee the result to be ordered thus? I tried to look this up, but haven't found the answer to this. In there docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) they seem to take this order for granted without explicitly mentioning it. As far as I know, however, every query result is only guanranteed to be ordered when we apply an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner agreed; the ordering is only implied by the documentation, but it really doesn't make any sense for it to be output any other way.

Answer (score 2):

Try below query.

```
SELECT * FROM states_YourtableName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Total '+[state] State ,'' Item ,SUM(Amount) Amount
    FROM states_YourtableName GROUP BY [State]
```

You will get an output as below

```
state   Item    Amount
A        X      100
A        Z      100
B        X      150
B        Y      200
Total A         200
Total B         350
```

Comment: This should be `UNION ALL`. And then you should think of a way to order your result rows. With the current query you could get any order (e.g. Total B, A | Z, B | X | Total B, ...). Ordering by the first result column wouldn't work well either, because you'd get A, B, Total A, Total B, Z, Total Z for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be `UNION ALL`. If it suffices to show the state instead of 'Total <state>', this becomes:

```
select state, item, amount from mytable
union all
select state, null, sum(amount) from mytable group by state
order by state, case when item is null then 2 else 1 end, item;
```

Result:

```
State | Item | Amount
------+------+-------
    A |    X |    100
    A |    Z |    100
    A |      |    200
    B |    Y |    200
    B |    X |    150
    B |      |    350
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not working as an excel file, it is mostly used to store and process data. If you want to store that data(the Total) in SQL in my opinion the best way to do it is to create another table where you can keep your totals.

If you try just to print the totals in your screen you can check the link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by with Rollup

**Try this -**

```
declare @Data table
([State] varchar(20), Item varchar(20), Amount int )

Insert into @Data
values
(    'A',      'X',      100),
(    'B',      'Y',      200),
(    'A',      'Z',      100),
(    'B',      'X',      150)

Select [State], Item, Sum(Amount) Amount
From @Data
Group by [State], Item with Rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `grouping sets`.  It provides much more control than `rollup`:

```
select state, coalesce(item, 'Total') as item,
       sum(amount) as amount
from t
group by grouping sets ( (state, item), (state) );
```